# Associate two models through belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, belongs-to

I have two ActiveRecord models, `A` and `B`.  `A has_many :B` and `B belongs_to :A`.  Naturally, `B` has an `a_id` column.

I have a bunch of `A`'s and every time I create a new `B`, I want to associate it with an `A` if certain conditions hold.

Currently, I'm retrieving the possible `A`'s and linking one to a `B` like so:

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :a_id
    belongs_to :a

    def link_to_a
        possible_as = A.where(some: conditions)
        self.a = possible_as.find_by_other-foreign-key_id(self.other_id) if possible_as != nil
        # Then I have to perform an operation on the b's a such as:
        self.a.linked_to_b_at = Time.now if self.a != nil
    end
end
```

This seems smelly.  Is there a better way to link the two models?  I thought making the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships explicit would help me.  I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B has a belongs_to relationship with A, then the way you created your B records is incorrect. You got to use the `build` method to create dependent records.

For example:

```
def create_b_records
 a = A.find(some_id)
 a.build_b(new_record_attributes)
 a.save 
end
```

Now, with that, retrieving all B records for a particular set of A records becomes quite straightforward:

```
possible_as = A.where(some_condition)
possible_as.each do |possible_a|
 possible_a.b #Do whatever you want to do with these B records
end
```

Comment: So I would put the `create_b_records` method in the BController?  Then when my BController's create action is called I call my create_be_records method with whatever parameters I need?  I think this could work and seems more in line with the idea of accessing the B through an A.

Comment: If you put your logic of creating B records in A's create action, it would save you an extra lookup operation. (If your method is in B's controller, you'll first have to find an A record and create a B record out of it.  Whereas in A's create action, you already have the A record, and you can call the build method to create a B record.)

Comment: That said, it doesn't matter where you create your B records but how you do it.  The build helper method leverages association information from your Rails models and creates dependent records for you.  So, as long as you use this helper, you won't have to worry about gluing stuff together.

Answer (score 1):

Add an after_create filter that makes the association

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :a_id
  belongs_to :a
  after_create :link_to_a

  def link_to_a
    update_attribute(:a_id, find_a )
  end

  def find_a #returns id of a
    your logic to find a
    ...
   end
end
```

Then create model B like you normally would.
Take a look at this, it has complete examples for managing that type of association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The difference between the posts and comments example is that you always know the post.  That way, you can access the comment through the post.  The analogy in my case would be me always knowing the `A` and simply accessing `B` through the `A`.  However, in my case, I only know the `B` and would like to link a `B` with an `A` from a large pool of `A`'s.  Do you see the difference?

Comment: you would run a POST request to /A/:A_id/B and the data would be the B model that you are creating. Then in the controller you would have logic to create the association.

Comment: I don't know A.  How can I POST to /A/:a_id/B if I don't know A's id until I create the B?  For example, I have 500 A's with a time attribute.  I send a POST request to /B/create and I want the B to belong to the A who's time attribute is closest to the Time.now when the controller receives the POST request to create a new B.

Comment: Hmm this is in spirit what I'm doing already.  Using an after_create filter is a good addition.  I still have the messy logic needed to find the proper A to associate the B with though.  So my question is focused on eliminating that mess.  After discussing with you though and reading the other answer, It seems I may not be able to avoid messy logic for finding the appropriate A.

Comment: You could create a class method for A that finds an A given a B model. Then in the logic where you create a the B model you simple set it to the param before you save it. I would go for the filter thou. Also encapsulate the finding logic in some method that returns A